# Microsoft LiveSearchService returning ClientError

Tags: livesearch

We have been using Microsofts LiveSearchService successfully for a number of years but just over a week ago it stopped working. It now returns the error

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Client error

This happens on line 79 of the Reference.cs file provided by Microsoft:

> object[] results = this.Invoke("Search", new object[] {parameters});

I build a SearchRequest object before calling LiveSearchService.Search() and everything looks fine in here, it has the correct appID and is passing a simple query string to the correct site address.

My network administrator assures me that there are no issues with our firewall which would stop any traffic trying to reach the api.search.live.net site and I can access this URL with our appID fine which returns the expected XML.

I have also tried changing the offset to 10 in case the search term was returning a ridiculous amount of results but this made no difference.

We have IIS7 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine and the website is written in C#.NET 3.5 using VS 2008.

I am at a loss as to what to try next so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Bing.com](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/05/17/bing-developer-update-2.aspx),

> ...Bing Search API 2.0 AppIDs are decommissioned on August 1, 2012. On and after this date, AppIDs will no longer return results. Developers can continue using the API by signing up for the Windows Azure Marketplace or by submitting a request if greater query volume is needed.

There are pricing plans and a migration guide [here](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44).